# google cardboard in unity 2019.4

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I am developing a virtual reality (VR) app using Unity 2019.4, specifically designed for Google Cardboard. However, I am encountering a challenge in implementing the feature that allows users to switch between the immersive VR mode and a regular 360-degree mode.

If anyone has experience with this and can offer guidance or assistance, I would greatly appreciate it. Please provide detailed instructions or code snippets on how to achieve the seamless transition between VR and 360-degree modes within the Unity environment. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!